# Taylor expansion of a Neural Network

Tags: taylor-expansion, neural-networks

Let $f(\mathbf{x})$ represent a trained neural network with ReLU() activation functions and input $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ ($\mathbf{x}$ could be, for example, an image with dimensionality $d$). Let's assume that if $f(\mathbf{x}) > 0$, the network recognized the input and if $f(\mathbf{x}) < 0$, the network does not recognize or understand the input.

The series expansion of the network $f(\mathbf{x})$ can be written as:

$$f(\mathbf{x}) = f(\mathbf{x_0})+(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x_0})\cdot \nabla f(\mathbf{x_0}) + (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x_0})\cdot \nabla^2 f(\mathbf{x_0})\cdot (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x_0}) + \dots$$

I would like to know, what the terms of the Taylor Series (especially the first three) say about the networks behavior and what $\mathbf{x_0}$ would represent in such a case. What for example would be a good choice for $\mathbf{x_0}$?

Comment: At first look it seems to be a $x_0$ such that $f(x_0) = 0$

Comment: @Cesareo Can you please explain why that is the case?

Comment: @Samuel First glances aren't perfect, and $f(x_0)=0$ does not have to hold. For classical neural networks that are smooth everywhere (NOT relu activation), any choice of $x_0$ works.

Comment: @Samuel Because the frontier variety is $f(x) = 0$ and the output should attend values $> 0$ and $ < 0$. Any way, if the nn is analytic theoretically any point would suffice.

Comment: @HansMusgrave Good point! Let's say the network has ReLU() activation functions. What would that change? I also updated the question. I forgot to mention that the network's activation functions are ReLU()s.

Comment: I'm not sure really. For functions of a single variable, the series expansion only converges in the smallest circle in the complex plane containing no non-smooth points. I imagine something similarly bad happens with multivariate inputs. When you consider how many ReLU's are being applied in a neural network, it's probably hard to find a large region where the series would converge (i.e., where the series would not hit a corner).